# Code working fine in firefox not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, w3c

I have gone through couple of same questions also, but no one can give me understanding that what is happening in my code. My code is:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

            console.log(" in navigator If");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, null, {
                enableHighAccuracy : true,
                maximumAge : 1000,
                timeout : 0
            });

        } else {
            console.log("in Navigator else");
            alert("Browser doesn't support location detection. Please pass latitude & longitude for current location in URL. Thanks.");
    }
```

this code working fine in firefox but not in chrome
I am using Mac, Jboss .
In Chrome control doesn't go in any of condition (neither if , nor else )

Comment: What error message do you get (if any) in the chrome console?

Comment: @jonnynnoj: there is no error in console, and not even chrome asked permission for location..

Comment: Just tested it and I got the "in navigator If" message, so your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: i have console.log() just before if condition also. That is getting printed. I Put it on my dev server, Still not working in Chrome , in any of user using Mac. Any hint , what can happen? BTW what machine you are using , because where ever I am testing there is Mac (chrome 23)

Comment: @@jonnynnoj: great, its is asking permission on one of my colleague chrome(So might be problem with my chrome), but still no latitude, longitude information passed ... inside if condition but no location detected.

Comment: I found problem, It was my timeout attribute. its was set zero, dont know how but It seems firefox override this value and chrome can't work with that , so by changing that attribute I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.geolocation doesn't work if you are directly running from the filesystem on chrome. Make sure the file is hosted on some local web server.

Comment: I mentioned that I am using Jboss, File is servered from Jboss

Comment: then its weird. Do let me know, if you get any solution.